# Função automatica PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Eu preciso que todo dia, o sistema envie pedidos de envio para os correios. Como posso fazer isso automaticamente, sem precisar que algum usuário carregue a página ou qualquer coisa do tipo?

Usaria a mesma lógica de fazer algo automaticamente sem interação do usuário (sem precisar fazer algo, abrir alguma página ou coisa do tipo) em outras coisas, não achei nada parecido até agora.

É possível fazer isso com PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tarefas cron / Cron job,

**Como funciona:**

crie um arquivo php que execute a função que você precisa, e quando voce abrir ele no http ele vai executar o que voce programou, agora só precisa algo automatico para ficar abrindo o arquivo por você, então hospede e use os recursos da hospedagem, na sua hospedagem configure o Tarefas cron para executar ele de tanto em tanto tempo automatico, o Windows tem a função nativo mas não lembro onde, o linux se chama cron job eu acho. O Suporte da hospedagem te ajudará para usar lá, é uma configuração no próprio painel de controle.

Answer (score 2):

Use o ***CRON***!

Deixando mais claro, o **CRON** é como se fosse uma pessoa que irá entrar no link que você programar de tempos em tempos.

Minha dica para você é usar uma hospedagem que seja Linux, pois a maioria tem o **CRON**. Um exemplo de configuração para executar um script:

```
Minuto: *
Hora: *
Dia: *
Mês: *
Ano: *

Comando: curl http://www.meusite.com.br/script_a_executar.php
```

Com esse comando o **CRON** executará o `script_a_executar.php` de 1 em 1 minuto.

Caso você queira programar 1 vez ao dia:

```
Minuto: 0
Hora: 0
Dia: *
Mês: *
Ano: *

Comando: curl http://www.meusite.com.br/script_a_executar.php
```

Pesquise como configurar o **CRON**, assim você saberá como definir o tempo que você precisa.

Comment: Acho que não tem motivo para executar um CURL, ainda mais usando o domínio ao invés do IP, fazendo buscar por um DNS. Acho que o mais fácil, se o Cron estiver no mesmo servidor do arquivo, ou na mesma rede, é definir um comando como "php -q /local/do/arquivo.php", é mais rápido.

Comment: Isso depende. Se for um framework e tiver controller você não conseguirá chamar app/controller.php