# Substituir CRON

Tags: php, cron

Fiz um script `PHP` que tem que ser executado sempre, geralmente de 1 a 1 segundos ou no máximo 2 a 2 segundos. O problema é que configurei no CRON várias linhas de comando para executar de 1 em 1 segundos, mas o CRON muda a configuração automaticamente, pois acho que sobrecarrega o servidor.

Minha dúvida é que gostaria de colocar o script para executar de **X** em **X** segundos sem mesmo ter nenhum usuário no site. Teria uma forma sem usar o CRON ?

Comment: Rode o PHP **pelo console** em loop infinito, com um sleep de 2 segundos, muito mais simples.

Comment: Só um detalhe: rodar pelo console não é isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121742/ - aqui você está chamando o servidor de páginas com o cURL. Dá na mesma que alguém acessando a página. Para tarefas constantes, tem que rodar o PHP pelo console.  `php nomedoscript.php`

Answer (score 1):

O menor intervalo que `cron` aceita é [um minuto](http://www.cronmaker.com/), ou seja, você não consegue usar o cron para rodar processos com segundos de diferença, diretamente.

No entanto o que você pode fazer é agendar um programa "disparador" que roda por um minuto, e esse programa dispara o outro com intervalo de segundos.

Uma solução um pouco mais estável é fazer esse "disparador" não parar nunca, agendar para o disparador rodar no [@reboot](http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html), e além disso agendar também para rodar pelo agendamento normal, digamos, a cada 15 minutos. Tem de por alguma forma de monitoração ou [trava](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex) para evitar rodar em paralelo, mas essa solução garante que o programa "se recupere" caso dê alguma coisa errada e inesperada.

---

A solução com loop infinito, sem reinicio, seria algo assim: No cron tab:

```
@reboot "/caminho/do/script/disparador.sh" &
```

E o arquivo `disparador.sh` algo assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do curl "LINK"; sleep 2; done
```

Comment: Tinha feito um loop infinito e no fim dele coloquei `sleep(1)`. A cada 1 minuto executava isso, mas começou a dar erro 500 no site inteiro.

Comment: Provavelmente por conta da repetição. Roda a cada minuto, loop infinito, então em alguns minutos terá centenas de cópias rodando em paralelo, o que provavelmente derruba servidor. Por isso a primeira solução de roda um minuto só. Pelo menos dá chance do servidor liberar recursos.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli o loop infinito é melhor nesses casos, mas tem que rodar o PHP pelo console, e não pelo servidor de páginas.

Comment: @Bacco como poderia fazer isso ? Sou leigo nessa parte

Comment: @AndréLFSBacci e no meu caso que é um link ? Pois uso o CodeIgniter e se eu chamar somente o controller ele não irá executar, preciso chamar o link, como faria no caso do reboot ?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli em vez de você rodar o `curl [endereco]`, você roda o `php [seu arquivo]`

Comment: @AndréLFSBacci esse arquivo `disparador.sh` que você deu de exemplo seria programado no `Cron` a cada 1 minuto (* * * * *) mas na realidade quando o cron executar ele irá fazer requisições de 2 em 2 segundos ?

Comment: Uma coisa não tem a ver com outra. O `cron` tem limitação por minuto, não consegue ser mais rápido que isso. Mas o `disparador.sh` não tem essa limitação. Ele pode disparar outro comando a cada segundo, cada dois segundos (como no exemplo acima). O que você faz é resolver o problema em duas partes. Primeiro cria o seu PHP que, sozinho, faz o que precisa fazer, de segundo em segundo. Depois você usa o cron para "só" levantar esse programa. Tem de por travas **no PHP** para evitar rodar dois ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score -1):

O caminho é o tarefas cron mesmo.

Comece a repensar se realmente é necessário de 1 em 1 segundo ou se você pode mudar algo no codigo para ser um pouquinho mais demorado, afinal, não tem ninguem no site no momento, um ajax no lado do cliente é aceitável, mas tarefas cron ao lado do servidor de um em um segundo até mesmo sobrecarrega e muitas hospedagens nem mesmo permitem a execução, normalmente o mínimo é 1 minuto.

Comment: Engraçado é que miguem levantou essa bandeira da viabilidade, não vejo como uma informação possa mudar 60 vezes em 1 minuto, coitado do operador. Em um banco grande o retorno dessa requisição poderia ser desastroso para o projeto. E como disse dependendo do host eles nem liberam, o código vai executar e depois vai ser bloqueado por uso indevido de recursos.