# Fazer consulta em um Web Service a cada 1 minuto

Tags: php, web-service

Tenho um Web Service em JSON, o qual estou consultando através de uma pagina em PHP e salvando os dados num banco em MySQL.
Esse Web Service contém informações de alguns sensores e, a cada 1 minuto queria fazer essa consulta e salvar esses dados no banco.
Como eu faria para fazer essa consulta temporizada?

Comment: Tentou um agendamento com o [cron](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2827/91) ?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55251/ |http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121735/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2818/

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia amigo, voce esta usando windows ou linux ?

Fiz isso usando windows, que pega informações de web service através de uma pagina PHP  e grava de hora em hora.

Como uso windows como servidor eu fiz o seguinte, criei uma .BAT  com o seguinte codigo.

```
@ECHO OFF

:start

"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\atualizaCadastro\Atualizar.php"
```

E programei nas tarefas no windows para rodar esta bat de hora em hora.

Agora é só voce adaptar para usar em um linux.

obs: se tiver algum include na sua pagina , o mesmo tem que conter o caminho todo desde o c:....